# Ebean missing from Play 2 Module for Java

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I created a new project in IntelliJ 13 using the Play 2 Module for Java project template and noticed that the `# Ebean configuration` is missing from `conf/application.conf`.

Being new to both Play Framework and IntelliJ I tried following the Play introductory video and got stuck where I need to extend the Ebean Model class. The problem is that the class doesn't appear in the Import class dialogue.

I've tried adding the source directory to these files to `File → Project Structure → Libraries` but that didn't work.

If `import play.db.ebean.Model;` is added IntelliJ complains with `cannot resolve symbol 'db'`.

What do I need to do to have my project include the Play Ebean classes?

Answer (score 8):

The method to enable ebean support has changed in play framework. Now it is done using an external dependency. From the documentation:

To enable it, add the Play Ebean plugin to your SBT plugins in project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

And then modify your build.sbt to enable the Play Ebean plugin:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

Comment: This is described in the migration guide for Play 2.4 https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24

Answer (score 4):

Inside the build.sbt file make sure "javaEbean" is listed like the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean
}
```

Then, run "play clean compile" and "play idea" consecutively.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please assits, where I can read information about build.sbt and what should be in it?